# Sum of two integers Tuple in C#

Tags: c#, sum, tuples

I am trying to solve this question just as a preparation for a jobb interview: 
Write a function that, given a list and a target sum, returns zero-based indices of any two distinct elements whose sum is equal to the target sum. If there are no such elements, the function should return null.

For example, FindTwoSum(new List() { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, 12) should return any of the following tuples of indices:

1, 4 (3 + 9 = 12)

2, 3 (5 + 7 = 12)

3, 2 (7 + 5 = 12)

4, 1 (9 + 3 = 12)

Here is what i have done so far

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(List<int> list, int sum)
    {
        List<Tuple<int, int>> ListOfInt = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
        for (int i=0; i<list.Count; i++)
        {
            for(int j=0; j<list.Count; j++)
            {
                if (list[i] + list[j] == sum)
                {
                    ListOfInt.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(i,j));
                }
            }
        }

        foreach ( var elemt in ListOfInt)
        {
            return elemt;
        }
        return null;

    }
```

The problem is that all results are found and saved in the Tuple: but i still cannot print out the result to the console. I think there is somthing wrong at the `foreach` statement. 
In the main method i am writing following to print the result to the console:

```
Console.WriteLine(FindTwoSum(new List<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, 12));
```

Any recommendations please :)?

Comment: `but i still cannot print out the result to the console`->What do you mean with that? You don´t know what commands to use.

Comment: Using `Tuple` for this problem sounds wrong for me.

Comment: Shouldn't you use yield return elemt rather than retrun elemt!

Comment: OK, so what's the error? Nothing printed? Wrong answer printed? Partial answer printed?

Comment: Your task is to write a program which "returns zero-based indices **of any two distinct elements** whose sum...". So, you don't need to gather and output all of them. Am I right?

Comment: It didnt print the result because it returns from the first iteration to the main method. a foreach loop in the main method could be a solution, but i am looking for more efficient solution

Comment: Doesn't 'any two **distinct** elements' mean that the result may not be a sum using the same incides. Perhaps you need to check that `i != j` ? Or am i wrong?

Comment: @Dbuggy That is a good one! He could test that with `FindTwoSum(new List<int> { 1, 6, 28, }, 12);`. Edit: How about `FindTwoSum(new List<int> { 1, 6, 28, 6, }, 12);` then? Do we allow the index tuple `1,3` there, since the indices are distinct, but the two elements of which they are indices, are equal as values (but not identical as instances).

Comment: and what about `FindTwoSum(new List<int> {6, 6}, 12)`... Distinct elements on indices or value.

Comment: @Dbuggy I was just editing that into my comment. Good question.

Answer (score 5):

Well, if `a + b = sum` then `b + a = sum`, so you can cut the inner loop and return *two pairs at once*; another issue and *counter example* for your current implementation is that `a + a = sum` doesn't count, e.g.

```
  {3, 6, 9}, 12
```

should return only

```
  0, 2 // 3 + 9
  2, 0 // 9 + 3
```

and not

```
  1, 1 // 6 + 6 is wrong
```

I'd rather implement the solution returning `IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>>`:

```
  // Are you given List<int>? What about int[]? IEnumerable<int> is a much better choice 
  public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> FindTwoSum(IEnumerable<int> items, int sum) {
    // Validate Arguments (the method is public one!)
    if (null == items)
      throw new ArgumentNullException("items");

    var list = items.ToList();

    for (int i = 0; i < list.Count - 1; ++i)   // last line doesn't count
      for (int j = i + 1; j < list.Count; ++j) // note j = i + 1
        // if ((list[i] + list[j] == sum) && (list[i] != list[j])) { // distinct values and indexes
        if (list[i] + list[j] == sum) { // distinct indexes only
          yield return new Tuple<int, int>(i, j);
          yield return new Tuple<int, int>(j, i);                
        }
  }
```

In case of you want *distinct values* as well as *distinct indexes* the condition instead of

```
  if (list[i] + list[j] == sum)
```

should be

```
  if ((list[i] + list[j] == sum) && (list[i] != list[j]))
```

Distinct *values*, but not *indexes* is not a case, since `a[i] == a[i]` so whenever indexes are not distinct neither the values. And we have the condition

```
  if ((list[i] + list[j] == sum) && (list[i] != list[j]))
```

Test:

```
  // note that I can pass an array (int[]) or list (List<int>) whatever collection
  String report = String.Join(Environment.NewLine, 
    FindTwoSum(new int[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, 12));

  // (1, 4)
  // (4, 1)
  // (2, 3)
  // (3, 2)
  Console.Write(report);
```

Comment: What is your opinion on the case `FindTwoSum(new List<int> { 1, 6, 28, 6, }, 12);`. Do you think the wording _"zero-based indices of any two distinct elements whose sum is equal to the target sum"_ means it is OK with distinct indices pointing to `List<>` elements with the same value?

Comment: @Jeppe Stig Nielsen: nice note! I've edited the answer; in case of not only *distinct indexes* but *distinct values* are required the condition within loop should be changed.

Comment: Dbuggy noted it at the same time as me, in comments to the question.

Answer (score 2):

Change the return value of your method to `IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>>`, then use `yield return` to return the value. You'll get the value when you enumerate the result in a loop (in your Main() method).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleApplication13
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var output = FindTwoSum(new List<int>() { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, 12);
            foreach (var x in output)
                Console.WriteLine(x.Item1 + " " + x.Item2);

            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }

        public static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> FindTwoSum(List<int> list, int sum)
        {
            List<Tuple<int, int>> ListOfInt = new List<Tuple<int, int>>();
            for (int i = 0; i < list.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < list.Count; j++)
                {
                    if (list[i] + list[j] == sum)
                    {
                        ListOfInt.Add(new Tuple<int, int>(i, j));
                    }
                }
            }

            foreach (var elemt in ListOfInt)
            {
                yield return elemt;
            }

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I like your solution, but is there any way to return the reuslt directly to the main method without using foreach loop in there?

Comment: Yes, but you will have to change the type of the return value. Tuple<int, int> only holds a pair of value while it should hold multiple values.

Comment: Counter example `{3, 6, 9}, 12` and the implementation will return `(1, 1)` among the others lines since `6 + 6 == 12` and that's not expected.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yes, you're right. It's a bug in the original code. I only change how the method returns the result. I also notice the optimization in your code.

Answer (score 2):

I noticed a potential problem in your example, given the wording of the question. You mention distinct elements, but you seem to take no steps to ensure the values you are using are distinct. You also appear to be able to sum the same element (i ==j)!.

The solution below shows how you could avoid the problems above, as well as avoiding having to put elements in a list as you go:

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(int[] collection, int sum)
{
    int[] distinct = collection.Distinct().ToArray();
    for (int x = 0; x < distinct.Length; x++)
    {
        for (int y = 0; y < distinct.Length; y++)
        {
            if (y != x && distinct[x] + distinct[y] == sum)
                return Tuple.Create(Array.IndexOf(collection, distinct[x]), Array.IndexOf(collection, distinct[y]));
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

You could then print this result using:

```
Tuple<int, int> result = FindTwoSum(new[] { 1,3, 5, 7, 9}, 12);
if (result != null)
    Console.WriteLine(result.Item1 + "," + result.Item2);
else
    Console.WriteLine("No solution!");
```

Comment: True, i got it wrong, i tought that i have to find all possible combinations bro. thats how i got it

Comment: Use it as a learning experience for your interview - make sure you carefully listen to / read the question and understand exactly what is being asked of you. Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you want to get fancy, you can use Linq:

```
var numbers = new List<int> {1, 3, 5, 7, 9};

int target = 12;
var items = numbers.Select((value, index) => new {index, value});

var hits = 
    from a in items
    from b in items
    where (a.index != b.index) && (a.value + b.value == target)
    select new {index1 = a.index, index2 = b.index};

Console.WriteLine(string.Join("\n", hits.Select(x => 
    $"{x.index1}, {x.index2} ({numbers[x.index1]} + {numbers[x.index2]} = {target})")));
```

**How it works**

This firstly uses `numbers.Select((value, index) => new {index, value});` to convert a list of numbers into a sequence of [value, index] tuples.

Then it effectively does a double-loop over that sequence of tuples by doing

```
from a in items
from b in items
```

which produces all combinations of items from the sequence of tuples.

Then it uses `where` to filter out all the items which have the same index (using `(a.index != b.index)` and also to determine which sums match the target value (using `(a.value + b.value == target)`).

Next it selects the results into a new tuple with properties `index1` and `index2`.

Finally it uses `string.Join()` to output the results from that tuple.

Answer (score 1):

This section will return as soon as it finds the first element in the List.

```
    foreach ( var elemt in ListOfInt)
    {
        return elemt;
    }
```

You need to return `List<Tuple<int, int>>` and then in your consuming code loop through printing out `Item1` and `Item2`

Comment: that true and that is what i noticed

Answer (score 1):

This loop:

```
    foreach ( var elemt in ListOfInt)
    {
        return elemt;
    }
```

will never "loop" back. In the first iteration, if there is a first element in the list, it will `return` which exits and abandons the loop.

If you really just want the first good pair, get rid of the `List<>`:

```
public static Tuple<int, int> FindTwoSum(List<int> list, int sum)
{
    for (int i=0; i<list.Count; i++)
    {
        for(int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            if (list[i] + list[j] == sum) // may want to append:   && list[i] != list[j]
            {
                return Tuple.Create(j, i);
            }
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Do you want to allow `i == j` in the returned tuple? (Edit: Changed my own code to disallow that.) You do not have to search both `i > j` and `i < j`, so choose one of them (as I did above).

You can use `Tuple.Create` when you want to make a new `Tuple<,>`.

Comment: In your case this code is going to return just one elemet from the Tuple.

Comment: @moji Absolutely. That is what I said. It is just like your own code. Note the question says: _should return any of the following tuples of indices_ That I understand as you want just any ***one*** pair ("tuple"), not a whole series of pairs (series of tuples).

Comment: Ohhhh ok! no what i am doing am trying to find all possible combinations

Comment: @DmitryBychenko I did change my answer to have `j<i` before you send that comment. But your comment applies to an old version of my answer. Note: I return only a single pair, not all of them.

Answer (score 1):

I'm one of those LINQish fans. So I just wrote the function with LINQ methods:

```
private static IEnumerable<Tuple<int, int>> FindTwoSum(IEnumerable<int> candidates, int expectedSum)
{
    return candidates.SelectMany((Lhs, LhsIndex) => candidates.Select((Rhs, RhsIndex) => new { Rhs, RhsIndex }).Where(r => r.RhsIndex != LhsIndex).Select(r => new { Lhs, r.Rhs }))
                        .Where(pair => pair.Lhs + pair.Rhs == expectedSum)
                        .Select(pair => Tuple.Create(pair.Lhs, pair.Rhs));
}
```

The hard part is to create all pairings in the first step. I simply get for each value additionally the index and then create pairs for all combinations where the index are different. After that it gets quite easy to simply check if they sum up to the expected value and create the desired tuples for the output.

To call this method you simply use:

```
var results = FindTwoSum(new[] { 1, 3, 5, 7, 9 }, 12);

foreach (var tuple in results)
{
    Console.WriteLine(tuple);
}
```

Comment: I which if i could find a good Tutorials about Linq!! i am having hard time to understand it hehe.. Linq is always the best way to solve such as quesiton!

Comment: @moji: Did you take a look at [EduLINQ](http://edulinq.googlecode.com/hg/posts/index.html) or [101 LINQ](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/101-LINQ-Samples-3fb9811b)?

Comment: Wow! nahh!! but i will !! hehe

Answer (score 0):

To read the values form a Tuple, you call .Item1, .Item2, etc.

```
var myTuple = new Tuple<int, string, string>(123, "Cat", "Dog");

var id = myTuple.Item1;
var pet1 = myTuple.Item2;
var pet2 = myTuple.Item3;
```